# Maximum Likelihood question

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood, likelihood-ratio, empirical-likelihood

I need to obtain the functional (i.e.: statistic obtained from the empirical distribution function) associated to the [most powerful test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformly_most_powerful_test) to contrast  $H_0: f_o$ vs. $H_1: f_1$, using a sample of size $n$.

In particular, my problem is that I don’t know how to construct this functional when I am not given a particular density function.

Using the [Neyman Pearson lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neyman%E2%80%93Pearson_lemma), I know that the maximum power test can be performed by computing the [likelihood ratio test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood-ratio_test) as:

$$ \Lambda(x_1,...,x_n)=\dfrac{{\sup}f_0(x_1,...,x_n)}  {{\sup}f_1(x_1,...,x_n)} $$

However since I don’t have a specific density function, I don’t know if this expression can be further operated or simplified in any way.

**EDIT**: Since I got no answers or comments, my guess is that there may be something wrong with my question.

**EDIT 2**: Per comments I understand now that I should use [non parametric statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-parametric_statistics) and instead of conventional maximum likelihood, the appropriate ratio to use should be based on [empirical likelihood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_likelihood).

In the introduction of this paper: [Empirical Likelihood Based Hypothesis Testing](http://arno.uvt.nl/show.cgi?fid=14262), there is a derivation of an statistic based on Empirical likelihood ratio to test $H_0: F = F_0$. However, since my data do not have the prerequisite of $F$ being a continuous distribution I am not sure if such reasoning can be applied to my original question.

Comment: It is not clear what your question is! Did you read about empirical likelihood?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen, thanks for your comment. My question is simpy how to derive the mathematical expression for the maximum power test $H_0: f_o$ vs. $H_1: f_1$ based on a sample of size $n$. The rest of the "information" above is just my take on the possible answer, which I guess is wrong at some point.

Comment: You write: "...when I am not given a particular density function. ...". Is this homework, since you say "not given"? To compute a likelihood ratio test, you need a model. What is your model? If your model is "non-parametric", you could read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_likelihood

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen. thanks again! this is indeed self study as tagged in the question. i have read your link and some other articles regarding empirical likelihood, but still I am not sure how to proceeed. I will update the original question